# Update Copy of Text File when Original Gets Modified

Tags: vb.net, ftp, copy, compare

Trying to write a fairly simple program that reads line by line a file from an ftp server, stores each line in a string, then writes that string to a local file on my drive. Now this is fairly easy and worked perfectly.

This is the part that gets tricky. Every time the ORIGINAL file on the ftp gets updated (a new line is added), I want that line to be added into my LOCAL file created earlier. I do NOT want to recopy the whole file contents if the files are different. I simply want to add the missing lines.

Is there any way this can be done ? Any tips will be appreciated. You don't have to submit a code. Let me know of how this can be done logically and I will try to write the code for it.

Regards

Comment: What does "copies a file from an ftp server to the local drive" mean? Do you mean "copies" as in "transfers via ftp", or do you mean "copies" as in "copy from drive C: to drive D:"? Your question is very vague, and you need to make it more clear what you're asking. Please edit again to do so, so we can try and help you. Thanks.

Comment: It reads every line in the text file on the ftp server, and writes every line in a local text file (c:/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a file "line by line" from an FTP server via FTP itself.

`FTP` is short for `File Transfer Protocol`, which is for transferring **files**. There's no way to do anything else via that protocol. If you want to access it "line by line", you're going to have to use something other than FTP.

Comment: Okay. I understand my whole question is confusing. Let's ignore it's on an FTP server for a second. Let's say I have two identical copies of a file. Copy 1 and Copy 2. Now every time Copy 1 gets a new line added at the end, I want this line to also be added in Copy 2.

Every 10 seconds, my program checks if Copy 1 and Copy 2 are identical. If yes, do nothing. If not, then the program copies the MISSING LINES (at the end of copy 1) to Copy 2. Is this possible WITHOUT having to re-create Copy 2's contents from scratch ?

Comment: Certainly, if you're willing to open `Copy1` and `Copy2` at the same time (which is not possible via FTP). You can ask Windows to notify you when a local or network drive file is changed, open both files, compare the line count, and then append lines not in `Copy1` over to `Copy2`. Both files would have to be available in their entirety though, in order to compare content. But you *can't* ignore the fact it's via FTP, as that's the question you asked here. If you have a *different question*, you need to post a new, *different* question.